# Can't copy Windows.edb ESE database using ShadowCopy

Tags: shadow-copy

I'm trying to copy opened file in Windows 10 by ShadowCopy V2.02 by Runtime Software. It works on other files but when I try to copy from this path C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Windows.edb it copies nothing. No mistakes, no result. I guess it's somehow connected with directory, I mean In that path are located important for OS files, so could Windows restrict ability to make a shadow copy?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Registry Key :

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\BackupRestore**

There are three Registry keys underneath that key :

**FilesNotToBackup**

**FilesNotToSnapshot**

**KeysNotToRestore**

If you examine these keys,

you might find the one that is preventing you from backing up that data.

If you would decide to remove some keys,

then first make a backup by exporting the entire key (**BackupRestore**).

Best to make a system restore point as well.

**Mind you, i use windows 8**, so there could be diferences in windows 10 for that key.

**Be careful with what you do in the Registry**.

Comment: Thanks a lot:) I found that keys but didnt decide to delete them, because I needed an example of .edb file and my mentor already sent it to me:D Sure it would work.